# Python 2 vs Python 3 imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-imaging-library, python-3.5

I have a script that is written in Python. The author decided to use new features only available in Python 3, so I had to update my version.

Now I am having trouble because the script crashes on an import statement, so I decided to do some debugging. I came to the conclusion that my Python 3 cannot import `Image` from `PIL`.

*In Python 2:*

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
```

*Does not give an error, but in Python 3:*

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 12 2015, 11:00:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

**Why is this happening and how can I fix this?**

Comment: PIL is not a standard library, you need to install it. I recommend the Pillow fork (updated PIL packaging and bug fixes).

Comment: Modules for Python 2 and Python 3 are installed separately.  Python 3 cannot "share" modules that you already installed under Python 2.  If you start using Python 3, you need to install Python 3 versions of any libraries you want to use.

Comment: Did you install pillow on your Python 3 install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIL is not a standard library; you installed it for Python 2, but that installation is not (and cannot be) used by Python 3.

Install PIL (or rather, the Pillow fork) explicitly in Python 3 as well:

```
python3 -m ensurepip  # optional, makes sure pip is installed
python3 -m pip install Pillow
```